# Tengo un problema a la hora de leer datos por teclado dentro de un ciclo while en Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa de consola extremadamente sencillo en el que introduzco en la consola o terminal unos datos pertenecientes a un articulo, los datos son el nombre del articulo, el código del articulo, el precio del articulo y la cantidad del articulo, luego imprimo en consola esos datos que se acaban de ingresar, todos estos datos que estoy leyendo los leo dentro de un ciclo while, después de leer todos los datos le pregunto al usuario si quiere seguir ingresando los datos de otro articulo, si responde 1 se ejecuta otra vez el ciclo, si responde 0 se sale del ciclo y finaliza el programa, el problema que tengo es que cuando ingreso 1 para ingresar los datos de otro articulo la parte del código donde ingreso el nombre del articulo se omite y queda el nombre como un String vacío, esto pasa solo con la variable del nombre del articulo y pasa en la segunda iteración del ciclo, hice este programa exactamente igual en C# y no tuve ese problema, ¿que creen que pueda estar pasando y como podría corregirlo?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Supermercado {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nombreArticulo;
        int codigoNumericoArticulo, cantidadArticulo, continuar = 1;
        double precioArticulo, precioParcialCompra = 0, precioTotalCompra;

        System.out.println("Ingrese los datos del primer articulo:");

        while (continuar == 1) {

            System.out.print("\nIngrese el nombre del articulo: ");
            nombreArticulo = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Ingrese el codigo del articulo: ");
            codigoNumericoArticulo = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Ingrese el precio del articulo: ");
            precioArticulo = scanner.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad del articulo: ");
            cantidadArticulo = scanner.nextInt();

            precioParcialCompra = precioParcialCompra + (precioArticulo * cantidadArticulo);

            System.out.println("\n+----------+------------------------------");
            System.out.println("| Nombre   | " + nombreArticulo);
            System.out.println("| Codigo   | " + codigoNumericoArticulo);
            System.out.println("| Precio   | " + precioArticulo);
            System.out.println("| Cantidad | " + cantidadArticulo);
            System.out.println("+----------+------------------------------");

            System.out.print("\n¿Quiere ingresar otro articulo mas?, digite '1' para ingresar uno mas o '0' para no ingresar mas articulos: ");
            continuar = scanner.nextInt();

        }

        precioTotalCompra = precioParcialCompra;

        System.out.println("\nEl precio total de la compra es: " + precioTotalCompra);

        scanner.close();

    }

}
```

Este es el codigo en C#:

```
using System;

namespace Supermercado
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string nombreArticulo;
            int codigoNumericoArticulo, cantidadArticulo, continuar = 1;
            double precioArticulo, precioParcialCompra = 0, precioTotalCompra;

            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese los datos del primer articulo:");

            while (continuar == 1)
            {

                Console.Write("\nIngrese el nombre del articulo: ");
                nombreArticulo = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.Write("Ingrese el codigo del articulo: ");
                codigoNumericoArticulo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Ingrese el precio del articulo: ");
                precioArticulo = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad del articulo: ");
                cantidadArticulo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                precioParcialCompra = precioParcialCompra + (precioArticulo * cantidadArticulo);

                Console.WriteLine("\n+----------+------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine($"| Nombre   | {nombreArticulo}");
                Console.WriteLine($"| Codigo   | {codigoNumericoArticulo}");
                Console.WriteLine($"| Precio   | {precioArticulo}");
                Console.WriteLine($"| Cantidad | {cantidadArticulo}");
                Console.WriteLine($"+----------+------------------------------");

                Console.Write("\n¿Quiere ingresar otro articulo mas?, digite '1' para ingresar uno mas o '0' para no ingresar mas articulos: ");
                continuar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            precioTotalCompra = precioParcialCompra;

            Console.WriteLine($"\nEl precio total de la compra es: {precioTotalCompra}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se pide la opción para continuar, por teclado se ingresa un número y un salto de línea.

`nextInt()` lee el número pero el salto de línea queda ahí todavía, por eso cuando el `while` continúa pide de nuevo el nombre del artículo y como hay un salto de línea piensa que ya se ha escrito algo y lo lee.

Para que eso no pase luego de pedir la opción de continuar se puede llamar el método `nextLine()` para que lea el salto de línea que quedó sin leer.

```
System.out.print("\n¿Quiere ingresar otro articulo mas?, digite '1' para ingresar uno mas o '0' para no ingresar mas articulos: ");
continuar = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // leer el salto de línea
```

Comment: Hola, tengo el mismo problema con otro ejemplo, la diferencia radica que ahora pido por teclado un `String` en vez de un `int` al final de ciclo `while`, probé esto en Python y no tuve problemas, ¿cual crees que pueda ser la solución ahora?

Comment: No me queda claro, podrías hacer una pregunta nueva para explicarlo mejor.